# React native reanimated 2 Animated.Text with shared value

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have the following react native component

```
import { memo } from "react";
import Animated, { SharedValue } from "react-native-reanimated";

export type WordHuntLettersSelectedProps = {
  lettersSelected: SharedValue<string>;
};

const WordHuntLettersSelected = ({ lettersSelected }: WordHuntLettersSelectedProps) => {
  return (
    <Animated.Text
      style={{
        color: "purple",
        fontWeight: 700,
      }}
    >
      {lettersSelected.value}
    </Animated.Text>
  );
};
```

My goal here is to display the value of `lettersSelected` whenever it is updated. This value comes from a parent component and initially looks like `const lettersSelected = useSharedValue("");`. However, I am having issues getting the text to render.

If I hard code the text value

```
<Animated.Text
      style={{
        color: "purple",
        fontWeight: 700,
      }}
    >
      Hard coded
</Animated.Text>
```

Then the text is displayed as expected. It looks like this is something to do with the shared value? I have found a hacky fix with [ReText](https://github.com/wcandillon/react-native-redash/blob/fd0b0ddb3b4c10ae88cf1f8a95890c7c5eb3c475/src/ReText.tsx) but I do not like how it is using a `TextInput` under the hood. I also looked into [react-native-animated-text](https://github.com/axelra-ag/react-native-animateable-text) but they do not support Expo.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Noted under [remarks](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/core/useSharedValue/#remarks):
"When you change the sv.value Reanimated will update the styles and keep the shared value in sync between the threads. However, this won't trigger a typical React re-render because a shared value is a plain JavaScript object."

Updating the text in the UI requires a React re-render, use useState instead.